# Office Add-ins with Blazor WASM

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, blazor-webassembly, office365-apps

I am trying to find out if Microsoft are working on support for Blazor WASM in the webview used in Office.

Are there a PR? og is it in the pipeline?

I have made 7 Blazor WASM app's for my company and would love to create add-ins with Blazor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no information for that. You can file a new feature request at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Note, Office add-ins support wide range of browsers - internet explorer in older Office versions, a chromium-based edge and etc. not only edge.